# My x axis is not in the right numeric order

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-wrangling

I'm trying to create a plot based on weeks in the year and ratings. For some reason my x-axis is not in the order of my data set, even though I have arranged it specifically.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


df <- df %>%
  arrange(match(weeks, c("0", "1 - 2022", "2 - 2022", "3 - 2022", "4 - 2022", "5 - 2022", "6 - 2022", "7 - 2022", "8 - 2022", "9 - 2022", "10 - 2022",
                              "11 - 2022", "12 - 2022", "13 - 2022", "14 - 2022", "15 - 2022", "16 - 2022", "17 - 2022", "18 - 2022", "19 - 2022", "20 - 2022",
                              "21 - 2022", "22 - 2022", "23 - 2022", "24 - 2022", "25 - 2022", "26 - 2022", "27 - 2022")))

eloRatingss %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = weeks, y = rating)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

[image: PLOT]

**How can I fix this so my x-axis is the same as my arranged values above?**

Thanks!

Comment: Your weeks column is a character. Hence your axis gets ordered alphabetically. To fix the order you could convert to a factor. If your dataset is in the right order you could e.g. use `forcats::fct_inorder` to achieve that.

Comment: With so many data points per week, how come you want a line plot? Wouldn't a boxplot be better?

Comment: The points relate to different 'teams' and I only gave a quick scope of what I wanted. I'm creating an app so only two 'team' points will show, so not so many points will be on there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coerce `weeks` to factor setting the levels in numeric order.
The levels are sorted with [`str_sort(., numeric = TRUE)`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_order.html) from package [`stringr`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stringr).

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df1 %>%
  pull(weeks) %>%
  unique() %>%
  stringr::str_sort(numeric = TRUE) -> levs_weeks

df1 %>%
  mutate(weeks = factor(weeks, levels = levs_weeks)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(weeks, rating, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test data

Note that after creating the test data set I make sure there is no `weeks` variable by removing it, the levels are created and sorted in the self-contained - given data - code above.

```r
weeks <- c("0", "1 - 2022", "2 - 2022", "3 - 2022", "4 - 2022", "5 - 2022", "6 - 2022", "7 - 2022", "8 - 2022", "9 - 2022", "10 - 2022",
         "11 - 2022", "12 - 2022", "13 - 2022", "14 - 2022", "15 - 2022", "16 - 2022", "17 - 2022", "18 - 2022", "19 - 2022", "20 - 2022",
         "21 - 2022", "22 - 2022", "23 - 2022", "24 - 2022", "25 - 2022", "26 - 2022", "27 - 2022")

set.seed(2022)
df1 <- data.frame(
  weeks = sample(weeks),
  rating = sample(2000:2500, length(weeks))
)

rm(weeks)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>